# Get all values from multidimensional array and print

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[que] => Array
        (
            [SomeWord] => Array
                (
                    [site] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 388
                        )

                    [site22] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5924
                        )

                    [site333] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 7140
                        )
                )

            [SomeWord22] => Array
                (
                    [site6565] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 389
                        )
                )
        )
```

Then, I want to get all the values (the Someword and then , 'site', '388', 'site22', 'site333') and print it in Heading Sub Heading and Text

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

May be your are expecting this , put your array in $data.

```
foreach($data['que'] as $key => $main){
echo "Main".$key;
foreach($main as $subkey => $sub){
echo "Sub".$subkey;
echo "text".$sub;
}

}
```